# How to Use css selectors in jest unit testing while using css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, css-modules

I'm using css modules in my react project and using web pack for bundling. While using Jest for testing, as the jest will try to import css files like normal JS files got the below error,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

The solution that I found is to use "identity-obj-proxy" to mock scss/css files.But now I cannot use css selectors to test components.For example

#### Test

```
it('renders 2 children', () => {
  expect(component.find('.mockyApp').children().length).toBe(2);
});
```

#### render method

```
render() {
  if (this.state.host) {
    return (
      <div className={style.mockyApp}>
        <div className={style.sidePage}>
          <SideBar clickHandler={this.setPage} selected={this.state.page}/>
        </div>
        <div className={style.mainPage}>
          {this.renderComponent()}
        </div>
     </div>
  );
 }
// ... .. rest of render method
}
```

I'm using **import style from './mocky.scss';** to import styles and using the style object for class names. Before using css-modules the above test used to work.Now my question is how will I be able to test using css selectors and what change needs to be done to make this work?. Googling didn't help

Comment: Is that 100% sure your render method? Because you are missing a bracket

Comment: of course not. It was a copy and paste mistake. Corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there exists a good solution for this problem yet.

Few ways you can still test it:

1) Add a static class name just for testing:

```
<div className={`${style.mockyApp} mockyApp`}>
  <div className={style.sidePage}>
    <SideBar clickHandler={this.setPage} selected={this.state.page}/>
  </div>
  <div className={style.mainPage}>
    {this.renderComponent()}
  </div>
</div>
```

2) Use a data attribute to target that element.

**Component**

```
<div className={`${style.mockyApp} mockyApp`} data-jest="mockyApp">
  <div className={style.sidePage}>
    <SideBar clickHandler={this.setPage} selected={this.state.page}/>
  </div>
  <div className={style.mainPage}>
    {this.renderComponent()}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Render**

```
it('renders 2 children', () => {
  expect(component.find('[data-jest=mockyApp]').children().length).toBe(2);
});
```

Both ways work but they include adding stuff to the DOM which gets shipped to production, which means more bytes being sent to your users.

If you are going with the second approach, you can consider writing a Babel plugin that strips out all `data-jest` attributes from the DOM in the transpilation process.